# "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, exception, fancybox

My asp.net application has a master page, a content page and a user control.

In the main master page there is a link which displays a fancybox as an iframe.
The iframe has a form to login to the page. The iframe is a new masterpage which has the content page of the login which has the user control of the login.

When the user clicks on the button to login the server side checks if the credentials are ok and if not it displays a message. All this with a custom validator.

My problem is that when the user first clicks the button to login it checks ok but if the credentials are not good and the user retypes them i get the following error on firefox

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:    
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: the state information is invalid  
for this page and might be corrupted http.../jquery-1.7.2.js
```

On the masterPage I have

```
<%-- jQuery --%>
  <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Template/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js") %>" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
<%-- jQueryUI --%>
<script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Template/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js") %>"
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Template/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.4.3.min.js") %>">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LoginLightBox").fancybox({
            width: 300,
            height: 750,
            scrolling: "no"
        });
        $("#RegistroLightbox").fancybox({
            width: 300,
            height: 750,
            scrolling: "no"
        });
    });

</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<body id="page1">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div >
<li style="display:inline"><a class="labelsTipolinks" id="LoginLightBox" href="Login.aspx?iframe=true">Login</a></li>
<li style="display:inline;color: #C53005;">|</li>
<li style="display:inline"><a class="labelsTipolinks"  id="RegistroLightbox" href="RegistroUsuario.aspx?iframe=true">Registro</a></li>
```

On the content page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Login" Src="~/Controles/Login.ascx" %>
```

And finally the user control:

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanelLoginIncorrecto">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CustomValidator ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="usuarioExistente_Validation"
                Display="Static" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" ID="vldLogin" 
                ValidationGroup="grupoValidacionLoginUsuario"
                Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, MsjError_LoginIncorrecto%>">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLoginLightbox" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="tableContent" style="float: right;">
    <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="btnLoginLightbox" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"
        ValidationGroup="grupoValidacionLoginUsuario" />
</div>
```

Please help this is going me crazy. I have already try enable eventvalidation set to false, sessions, response.cache.setno... etc but none worked.

**EDIT**

The line where i get the error is on jquery 1.7.2.js and is on the line that says jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );

**EDIT 2**

I ended up putting the fancybox as an inline element inside the master but it is not the solution i want. Please help me out!!!!!

Comment: Is this page hosted on a single server, or is there a chance it could be cross-posted to different servers in a load-balancing environment? If so, the encryption being used for the viewstate might be using different keys across the different servers and cause the problem you're experiencing. You might also investigate the MaxPageStateFieldLength property in web.config.

Comment: Its on a development enviroment, so the machine of the development is the server

Comment: Okay. Longshot. Here's a KB article that points to this problem as well, perhaps it would help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323744. You might try a "Clean Solution" and complete rebuild of your project because the problem in the KB article can be induced by changes in the location of ASP.NET temp files. If there is any "stale" information around in some of the metadata, that could tie into your problem.

Comment: I cleaned rebuiled but stills the same problem. One thing that is really **strange** is that if i focus after the first postback on both of the textboxs(username and password) and write some more characters there eventually works...extremely weird

Comment: Then I would strongly suggest that your viewstate is being corrupted by some of your javascript nested within your controls. ASP.NET performs a "sanity check" on the viewstate, and if changes are made to it outside the scope of what it can check, you'll get a corruption/failure as you've seen here.

Comment: I see. But it is weird the fact that if i focus on the textboxes before pressing the login button again works, i'll check with the viewstate, thx!

Comment: As per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16100143/845584) SO post, you may need to temporarily delete the `UpdatePanel` to see if it's masking/hiding an underlying error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After weeks of trying, i tried putting type:"iframe" and magically it worked! I have no idea what has to do but now it works :)
So the code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoginLightBox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        width: 300,
        height: 750,
        scrolling: "no"
    });
    $("#RegistroLightbox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        width: 300,
        height: 750,
        scrolling: "no"
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem in the past. I believe it deals with having `<% %>` in the `<head>` on the master page, however I may be mistaken. Replace your master page with this and let me know if it fixes the issue.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Template/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.4.3.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LoginLightBox").fancybox({
            width: 300,
            height: 750,
            scrolling: "no"
        });
        $("#RegistroLightbox").fancybox({
            width: 300,
            height: 750,
            scrolling: "no"
        });
    });

</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
<body id="page1">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <ul>
<li style="display:inline"><a class="labelsTipolinks" id="LoginLightBox" href="Login.aspx?iframe=true">Login</a></li>
<li style="display:inline;color: #C53005;">|</li>
<li style="display:inline"><a class="labelsTipolinks"  id="RegistroLightbox" href="RegistroUsuario.aspx?iframe=true">Registro</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it didnt work. Besides i cant remove the <% %> because the masterpage is referenced by other content pages that are not in the same folder. Anyways, thx for the advice.

Comment: Can you send me your `<%@ Master %>`?

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Proyecto.SiteMaster" %> is this what you mean? what part of the master you need? The important is what i put!

Comment: I've done some tests and without access to your code, it's difficult to say what the problem is.  However, my recommendation is to visit this site: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/, download the file, and apply it to your `<head>`.  Best of luck!