# Asp.Net UpdatePanel error

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, updatepanel

I use UpdatePanel in my aspx page and DropDownList with `onselectedindexchanged` method.

When run first time `onselectedindexchanged` method is working. But change selected again it return an error like that;

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" >
</asp:ScriptManager>

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
EnableEventValidation="false" ...  %>
```

Not : I have to Partial Rendering so i cant add `EnablePartialRendering="false"` to ScriptManager.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the UpdatePanel and follow the same steps to see what error you get. You error is something else, but the UpadtePanel hide the real error.

Comment: Thank u. But when i remove UpdatePanel all page is postback and it works.

Comment: Also enable the `EnableEventValidation=true` to see what you make wrong. (keep the UpdatePanel off, make the same steps, then you see your real issue)

Comment: Unfortunately i tried but not changed.

Comment: It was really about hide error. 
In script file an error which added as a reference
 <script src="../js/Detail.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
I found problem and it works.
 
Thanks Aristos.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Aristos' comment above, with my `Telerik` solution, I had to temporarily remove the `telerik:RadAjaxManager` to see the underlying error. This is similar to temporarily removing the `UpdatePanel`.

In my case, the error was: `TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.RepricingApproval_40D472CCAE59DB7A70B40FC6B029B430955A5ED87A7670652AA5B4D9D96A9A38' from assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]`

(BTW, the fix for the above was to set `EnableFlattening` to false).