# Event on other page not being fired and gives server error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, events

If I call a page in iframe everything works fine but it flickers whenever the iframe is loaded. To avoid flickering I called the aspx page in div instead of iframe.

This is How I load an aspx page in a div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#div1').load('frmChatRequest.aspx', function () {

            });
        }, 10000);
    });

</script>
```

But I got one Problem, which is I have grid view controls like button field and their event is not firing and it is giving this error `"The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."` What should I do?
This is the aspx page called in div

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div id="divConversation" 
        style=" width: 101%; height:174px; overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden">
    <asp:GridView  ID="gdvChatRequestRoom" style="background-color:ALICEBLUE;"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Width="358px" Height="57px" GridLines="None"
        BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="Black" 
        OnRowCommand="gdvChatRequestRoom_RowCommand"  >
        <Columns>
    ......
    ...........
    .............
```

this is the error[image]

Comment: Show code for rmChatRequest.aspx

Comment: please see the edits in question

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the problem that you download page content to the div. For this purpose it is better to use IFrame.

*Edit*
To avoid flickering inside iframe I can advice to place content of the rmChatRequest.aspx inside update panel and update it instead of realoading iframe fully. One of the solution is that you can add [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295201.aspx) control inside rmChatRequest.aspx page which will update content of the page (by updating update panel or etc). So, in this case you will have that content of the mChatRequest.aspx page is updated and postbacks work as expected because it is inside iFrame.

Note: that more ideal solution is to use SignalR to perform real time update then pool server every 1 second.

Comment: I was using Iframe but every time it was loaded,it flickered

Comment: @MangalPandey I update my answer with available solution to avoid flickering.

Comment: Its not necessary that target should be an iframe, it can be div element

Comment: @shadow If you want to show fully working aspx page inside other one then iframe is a way to go. It is not problem to add HTML content to div. BUT adding HTML content which is generated by ASPX page is not a very good solution. May be something will be shown, and maybe correctly, but such things as postback and server side events will not be work.

Answer (score 1):

Set EnableEventValidation to false in design page(.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" EnableEventValidation="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be having `runat="server"` for `div1`

Plaese check if it is. If present remove it and run the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#div1').load('frmChatRequest.aspx', function () {
                    type: "iframe",
        width: 300,
        height: 750,
        scrolling: "no"
            });
        }, 10000);
    });

</script>
```

Add This I found This is on This Reference:["The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783707/the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-and-might-be-corrupted-and-jquery)

Comment: Its not necessary that target should be an iframe, it can be div element